# Ordenar tupla pela chave em Python 3

Tags: python, lista, tupla, tuple

Tenho uma `lista_tupla = [(1, [1, 2, 3, 4]), (2, [5, 6, 7]), (3, [7, 8, 9]), (3, [10, 11, 12]), (4, [13, 14, 15])]` onde o primeiro índice de cada tupla é uma chave e o segundo índice é uma lista como acima.

Gostaria de saber: como faço para ordená-la pela chave? Tentei o seguinte comando:

```
lista_tupla_ordenada = lista_tupla.sort(key=lambda, x: x[1])
```

Mas não funcionou. Retorna:

```
>>> lista_tupla_ordenada = lista_tupla.sort(key=lambda, x: x[1])
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    lista_tupla_ordenada = lista_tupla.sort(key=lambda, x: x[1])
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Como posso resolver isso?

PS: sim, eu preciso de cada chave duplicada em minha tupla :P

Comment: Como diz a resposta, esse caso você  não precisa do lambda - por que está ordenando direto pelo primeiro item de cada tupla. Mas o que está errado aí é a vírgula depois da palavra `lambda` o correto seria 'lambda x: x[0]` - sem `,` depois de lambda - e tomando o elemento `0` (não elemento `1`) de cada tupla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já tem o mais dificil, agora é só:
**Ordenar crescentemente (menor para o maior):**

```
lista_tupla_ordenada = sorted(lista_tupla)
```

**Ordenar decrescentemente (maior para o menor):**

```
lista_tupla_ordenada = sorted(lista_tupla, reverse=True)
```